# Ошибка при загрузке картинки в нейросеть: ValueError: Error when checking input

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, keras, tensorflow

Пытаюсь загрузить изображение таким способом:

```
img_path = '2.png'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(300, 300), grayscale=True)
# Преобразуем изображением в массив numpy
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = 255 - x
x /= 255
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
prediction = model.predict(x)
```

Выходит такая ошибка:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_3_input to have shape (300, 300, 3) but got array with shape (300, 300, 1)

Как правильно преобразовать картинку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте убрать параметр `grayscale=True`, т.к. в таком виде `image.load_img` оставит всего один цветовой канал, а ваша модель ожидает три цветовых канала:

```
expected conv2d_3_input to have shape (300, 300, 3)
#            -----------------------------------^^^
```

Comment: спасибо действительно помогло